# Unresolved Class ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, parse-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

**Context:** 
Implementing Cloud Push Notifications on Android via `Parse Server`

as Backend and `Firebase Cloud` Messaging Service

**Goal:** Sending a push notification from `Parse` to the subject Android Application

**Problem:**
When injecting class `com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService` into `AndroidManifest.xml` file, it goes unresolved.

**Already-tried Solutions:**
Changing the Firebase and Parse packages versions in `build.gradle` (App File) as well as changing the dependencies versions in `build.gralde` (Project File)

Project files:

*AndroidManifest.xml* 
(Portion of the file where the error occurs)

```
<service
        android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

*build.gradle (Project)*

```
     buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

build.gradle (Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.sytech.uber"
            minSdkVersion 24
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        //Parse
        implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.20.0"
        implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.20.0"
        implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
        //Toasty  https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty
        implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
        //Firebase 
        implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: @VivekMishra I'm currently using https://back4app.com and so far it's going well, however, you are correct and I'll be migrating completely to Firebase real soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FirebaseInstanceIdService` is no longer usable. Use latest version of parse and `FirebaseMessagingService`

```
implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.21.0"
```

And use `ParseFirebaseMessagingService`

```
<service
    android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Well, it solved the problem, Thanks, Although my Goal of sending a notification from Parse Server hasn't been achieved yet. I'm still trying to determine the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Md. Asaduzzaman's answer, make sure to override the onNewToken() method in your custom FirebaseMessagingService, like in [this](https://medium.com/android-school/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated-50651f17a148) tutorial. (I just found the tutorial and thought it would be nice to share it if others are stuck with the same problem).

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.i("NEW_TOKEN", s);
}
```

We need to override it because:

"FirebaseInstanceIdService: This class was deprecated. In favour of overriding onNewToken in FirebaseMessagingService.

Once that has been implemented, this service can be safely removed."